# Check if string inside an array javascript

Tags: javascript

If i had an array of `days names` and i wanted to check for example if `sunday` - first letter capital or small - in this array what would be the best thing to do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [array.contains(obj) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may also use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var days = ["monday",
            "tuesday",
            "wednesday",
            "thursday",
            "friday",
            "saturday",
            "sunday"];

function isInArray(days, day) {
    return days.indexOf(day.toLowerCase()) > -1;
}

isInArray(days, "Sunday");  // true
isInArray(days, "sunday");  // true
isInArray(days, "sUnDaY");  // true
isInArray(days, "Anyday");  // false
```

Check the browser compatibility in [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).

Answer (score 4):

```
function is_in_array(s,your_array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < your_array.length; i++) {
        if (your_array[i].toLowerCase() === s.toLowerCase()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
var arr = ["hello","ToTo"];
is_in_array("toto",arr) //true
is_in_array("todto",arr) //false
```